# Spring Security concurrent session control max-session in Cluster Environment

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I am using Spring framework 4.0 Release version, along with Spring Security 3.2 Release version. I came across a situation where it is required to use feature to restrict number of active session of a same user id. By reading Spring Security document, I learned that Spring Security provides [this](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.0.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#concurrent-sessions) type of feature. I've tried implementing it that way. It is working fine (on single system). I've used custom UserDetailsService class with custom UserDetails class.

Now a question arise is that, how can I achieve this behavior in clustered environment? I am having a cluster environment with sticky session mechanism.

Answer (score 2):

You will need to implement a Custom SessonRegistry. You will need a way(pref: database) to share the sessions between the clustered nodes.

So when a user's successful authentication.. check if already there is a sessionId already assigned to the user (in the database). Then, invalidate the earlier one and save the new session Id.

Also, for authenticating the request, you will need to validate it using the Database.

Comment: Yes, that can be a way to manage concurrent sessions in clustered environment. One way I thought of is of having distributed caching. 

I was actually expecting any support from Spring framework itself, so that I don't need to care about active sessions of each users on each clusters. But it sounds that Spring Security does not provide it. I've read reference manual for Spring Security 3.2 Release. But hardly get information about `max-session` attribute on cluster environment.

Do you know any support from Spring framework for clustered environment?

Comment: To do so, according to you which way will be better? To have custom implementation of SessionRegistry interface or to have Session listener to handle user sessions?

Comment: Session Listener? how are you planning to do it. In one of my project, I have use combination of Custom SessionRegistry and ConcurrentSessionControlStrategy to achieve this

Comment: As of now I have two options. One is using SessionListener. The application I am working on currently have very limited amount of users. So by iterating all available sessions from SessionRegistryImpl. That is not a preferred way to handle. Another way is to implement own implementation of SessionRegistry. But I am having little knowledge on implementing a customized one. `ConcurrentSessionControlRegistry` is deprecated in Spring Security 3.2, which I am using.

Comment: By the way, How did you override behavior of `SessionRegistry` interface? I mean, I've tried to override it, but to perform the operation it require to have `SessionInformation` object. So, is there any way to assign custom SessionInformation instead of the one from Spring Security? Because I am storing session related information to the database using JPA & fetching data using sessionId require to have default argument constructor of the `SessionInformation`. So, I am stuck to that portion... Any hint!!

Comment: If you provide your own `SessionRegistry`, you can wrap a `SessionRegistryImpl` and in the delegate method to `getSessionInformation()` you can again wrap the `SessionInformation` in your own custom class that contains the extra information you need.

Comment: is Clustered environment still not supported out of the box in the latest release of Spring Session ?

Comment: A simple example here: https://dzone.com/articles/using-spring-session-for-concurrent-session-contro